# jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>

Tags: shell, curl, jq, apache-kafka-connect

I was following this [link](https://rmoff.net/2018/03/24/streaming-data-from-mysql-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect-and-debezium/) to stream data from mysql to kafka topic in my ubuntu machine.  There, in
**Kafka Connect setup** topic, when I run to check if my connectors are running with this(as suggested there):

```
curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors" | jq '.[]' | xargs -I mysql-connector curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors/mysql-connector/status" | jq -c -M '[.name,.connector.state,.tasks[].state] | \
join(":|:")'| column -s : -t| sed 's/\"//g'| sort
```

I got this error:

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell
> quoting issues?) at , line 1:
> [.name,.connector.state,.tasks[].state] | \
> jq: 1 compile error (23) Failed writing body (23) Failed writing body

I am totally stuck. Anyone please help if possible.
**N.B.:** This is not duplicate question, though question with similar headline exists but problem is different and I have checked them well.

Comment: Get rid of the trailing backslash.  Inside quotes, you don't need (or want) to escape the newline.

Comment: Also, replace `sed 's/\"//g'` with `tr -d '"'`

Comment: Better yet, just drop the `sed` and add a `-r` to the `jq`.  Not sure about your format, but `-r` is typically a better way to strip quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are abusing `\`. Use:

```
curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors" | 
jq '.[]' |
xargs -I mysql-connector curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors/mysql-connector/status" |
jq -c -M '[.name,.connector.state,.tasks[].state] |
join(":|:")' |
column -s : -t |
tr -d \" |
sort
```

It might be cleaner to put the `jq` all on one line, but the key point is that if you try to escape the newline inside single quotes, you end up with a literal backslash in the `jq` command that does not belong there.